# Export png from deckl map

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I'm using [react-map-gl](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl) with [deck.gl](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl) to load layers into mapbox.

I'm trying to export a png image of the map with layers but when download the image doesn't show the layers.

The layers are: one GeojsonLayer and one HexagonalLayer.

How can show layers in my png??

```
<MapGL
  ref={this.mapRef}
  {...viewport}
  className="mapbox"
  mapStyle={mapStyle}
  mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
  preserveDrawingBuffer={true}
  attributionControl={false}
  onLoad={this.handleLoad}
  onViewportChange={(viewport) => {
    viewport.width = "100%";
    viewport.height = "400px";
    this.setState({ viewport });
  }}
>
  <DeckGL layers={layers} onHover={this.onHoverDeckgl} viewState={viewport} />
</MapGL>;
```

// This is my method to download the image.

```
downloadImage = () => {
    const fileName = `${"Mapa"}_${moment().format(
        "DD_MM_YYYY_ HH_mm"
    )}.png`;

    const canvas = this.state.mapGL.getCanvas();
    canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I did it!!!

I fould a solution to combine canvas from mapbox and canvas from deckgl.

1. Aadd id to Deckgl Component and ref

   ```
   return (
        <DeckGL
           id="deck-gl-canvas"
           ref={this.deckRef}
           layers={layers}
           onHover={this.onHoverDeckgl}
           onLoad={this.handleLoad}
           viewState={viewport}
        >
           {this.renderTooltip()}
        </DeckGL>
   );

   // pass deck reference where will be action to download image
   handleLoad = () => {
       const deck = this.deckRef.current.deck;
       this.props.onGetDeckGL(deck);
   };
   ```
2. add ref to Mapbox Component and pass will be the action to download image
3. Call redraw to deck
4. Combine canvas on a third canvas

   ```
   downloadImage = () => {
       const fileName = "Map.png";

       const { mapGL, deck } = this.state;
       const mapboxCanvas = mapGL.getCanvas(
           document.querySelector(".mapboxgl-canvas")
       );
       deck.redraw(true);
       const deckglCanvas = document.getElementById("deck-gl-canvas");

       let merge = document.createElement("canvas");
       merge.width = mapboxCanvas.width;
       merge.height = mapboxCanvas.height;

       var context = merge.getContext("2d");

       context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
       context.drawImage(mapboxCanvas, 0, 0);
       context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
       context.drawImage(deckglCanvas, 0, 0);

       merge.toBlob(blob => {
           FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
       });
   };
   ```

Comment: Why redraw deck?

Comment: @HimanshuRawat because if not redraw it is empty. You download a transparent picture.